# Are Hashtable and hash tables the same (same data structure)?

Tags: hash

Are Hashtable and hash tables the same (same data structure)?
I think hash tables are composed of arrays + single linked lists. Does that mean Hashtable?

Comment: I took up the sofa.

Comment: hashtable  and hash tables are same

Comment: What do you mean by "Hashtable" and "hash tables"?

Comment: Hashtable is an implementation of a hash table. In other words, a hash table contains but is not limited to a Hashtable.

Comment: I don't get it. Which programming language are you talking about?

Comment: Java language, Hashtable is a class of jdk, hash table belongs to java data structure